# Add query to linq var

Tags: c#, linq

I never used this before. I need to add another member to the query. How can I add "link" to "source"?

```
 var titles = regexTitles.Matches(pageContent).Cast<Match>();
 var dates = regexDate.Matches(pageContent).Cast<Match>();
 var link = regexLink.Matches(pageContent).Cast<Match>();

  var source = titles.Zip(dates, (t, d) => new { Title = t, Date = d });

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
      var articleTitle = item.Title.Groups[1].Value;
      var articleDate = item.Date.Groups[1].Value;
      //var articleLink = item.Link.Groups[1].Value;

      Console.WriteLine(articleTitle);
      Console.WriteLine(articleDate);
      //Console.WriteLine(articleLink);
      Console.WriteLine("");
      }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just need another call to `Zip`. The first call will pair up the titles and dates, and the second call will pair up the title/date pairs with the links:

```
var source = titles.Zip(dates, (t, d) => new { t, d })
                   .Zip(link, (td, l) => new { Title = td.t,
                                               Date = td.d,
                                               Link = l });
```

or (equivalently, just using projection initializers):

```
var source = titles.Zip(dates, (Title, Date) => new { Title, Date })
                   .Zip(link, (td, Link) => new { td.Title, td.Date, Link });
```

(I sometimes think it would be nice to have another couple of overloads for `Zip` to take three or four sequences... it wouldn't be too hard. Maybe I'll add those to [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) :)

Comment: Thanks Jon. My two commented lines are showing an error. Unknown member 'Groups' and unknown type of variable 'articleLink'. Not sure if I have a mistake somewhere else. I am checking..

Comment: @Nullbyte: Please include the *exact* error message.

Comment: @Nullbyte: I've just changed your source code to include my declaration for `source` and uncommented your commented out lines... the only error is that you're using `value` instead of `Value`.

Comment: Grate. Problem solved. It is woring fine. I will follow the development. It looks quite powerfull and I am juststarting to use it.

Comment: @Nullbyte: Goodo. I found a typo in my first form after all, but I've corrected that now.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use `Zip` once more as in the below code:

```
var source = titles.Zip(dates, (t, d) => new { Title = t, Date = d });
                   .Zip(link, (d, l) => new { Title = d.Title, 
                                              Date = d.Date, 
                                              Link= l });
```